# How to change the target frame of a web response

Tags: java, html, http

Is it possible to change the target frame in my web response?

I make a request with target=_parent, but depending on how that request is processed I would like to change the target frame. Is there something I can set on my HttpServletResponse to change the target frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe so.  You've told the target window to load the output of that servlet as its new content.  If that servlet were somehow able to change its target, what would _parent display?